# RequestMapping is not identifying ?(question mark) as part of parameter passed with java REST Call

Tags: spring-mvc

Follow this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/abcd/id={id}","/abcd?id={id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

public ModelAndView test(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

I have specified two type of values above in my code. former works fine when we call the uri but later is not getting identified (i.e.) `@RequestMapping` is not identifying ?(question mark)
as part of parameter passed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should get params on URL using `@RequestParam` as a method parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abcd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(@RequestParam String id) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: [link](http://localhost:8080/<ProjectName>/rest/abcd?id=42084) I want make this call from my java code. How I will do that ?

Comment: Yes this works with single parameter can you please let me know in case of multiple parameters how to write the same because @RequestMapping(value = {"/EspDashBoard"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getCaseDesc(@PathVariable("groupId") String groupId,
   @RequestParam("subGroupID") String subGroupID,

Comment: @user1523256 you're mixing up PathVariables and RequestParams

Comment: You can combine both `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`: `@RequestMapping(value = "/EspDashBoard/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView getCaseDesc(@PathVariable("groupId") String groupId, @RequestParam("subGroupID") String subGroupID);` Example URL calling this method: `http://localhost:8080/app/controllerMapping/EspDashBoard/50?subGroupID=100`. `@PathVariable` is often used for mandatory parameters, as IDs.

Comment: Is it possible for a handler to handle both kind of requests? 1) http://localhost:8080/EspDashBoard/50?subGroupID=100 2) http://localhost:8080/EspDashBoard/50?subGroupID=100&secondID=100

If I define two separate controllers Spring complains and says "There is already a controller method ... mapped"

Comment: Just add another parameter to the method, with `@RequestParam`: `@RequestMapping(value = "/abcd/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam String subGroupID, @RequestParam String secondID);`. In case `secondID` is not passed as a parameter, you will receive a null value in the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

Question mark in urls (and uris) is used to separate parameters from the path.

`@RequestMapping` takes a path as it's `value` attribute. Hence it shouldn't contain question marks.

So basically your first case is interpreted as a path (although a strange one) and the second one is simply wrong.

Comment: I want to make url call like this :(http://localhost:8080/projectName/rest/abcd?id=42084). How I will do from my java code ?

Comment: Look at @jelies answer. One thing you should remember is to add a name for a request parameter you want to bind to your method parameter, so it becomes: `@RequestParam("id")  String id`. It would be a better idea to iclude id as a part of your path, so it becomes `http://localhost:8080/projectName/rest/abcd/42084`